# TFS 2013 git: git clone succeeds but git remote add fails. What am I doing incorrectly?

Tags: git, version-control, tfs

## Environment

### Server

- Win Server 2012
- TFS 2013 (12.0.21005.1)

### Client

- Win 7
- git version 1.9.0.msysgit.0

## State of Affairs

- git clone http://{TFS Project Collection URL}/_git/{Team Project Name}

  - Succeeds
- git remote add {alias} http://{TFS Project Collection URL}/_git/{Team Project Name}

  - Fails with message "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

I notice that the URL I'm supposed to use with git commands (http://{TFS Project Collection URL}/_git/{Team Project Name}) is also a valid URL that responds with html and shows the items in the repo via the web app.

## Question

What am I doing incorrectly?  Could it be that I need to configure TFS such that the URL of the repo (http://{TFS Project Collection URL}/_git/{Team Project Name}) "knows" how to reply to both the web app request and a request via git? Additionally, how can one troubleshoot an issue like this?

## Update

This question was 99% complete when I discovered my issue, so, following [the answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17847/194689), I'll just go ahead and post my question and immediately answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question and answer is useful, in that other git newbies using TFS might follow the "TFS configuration red herring" that I followed.  Instead, my problem was lack of familiarity with git: when I invoked the git clone command, the repo was pulled down to the working directory, of course, and so it succeeded, regardless of where my working dir was on disk.

However, **when I invoked the get remote add command, my working dir wasn't a git repo** (or the parent dir of a repo), nor did I pass the repo as an argument (not sure if that's possible).  I didn't realize that the git remote commands are relative to repos rather than (as I thought) being relative to global settings.  As I read the error message again ("fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"), it makes complete sense.  I had construed the message as referring to the remote repo; whereas, it was referring to my local repo.

Also, it makes sense that remote aliases be added to a particular repo rather than being global to a git installation, as one repo might push to GitHub; another to an on-premises TFS instance; etc.